# Latitude and Longitude not saving to record in Flow (other values are saving except for these)

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, geolocation, lightning-flow-builder, data-integration-rule

I need geolocation for my person accounts but Salesforce does not support this, So i created a flow as a workaround since Salesforce only support GeoCoding on Accounts, Contacts and Leads

Basically when a person account is created, the flow creates a contact with its address filled out(personmailingaddress -> contact address) the latitude and longitude are automatically filled out on the Contact record through 'Data Integration Rules'.(Since Salesforce supports Contacts)
Then the flow grabs the lat/long values form the Contact, and puts them into the PersonMailingLongitude and PersonMailingLatitude.

However my flow is not populating these.

So I added another fields just to see if the flow was working.

When the flow intially creates the Contact, I populate the 'Title' field on the Contact with the value of 'titlefromAccount'

Then I do the getRecords to look for the Contact I just created.

Then I update the PersonAccount with the data from the Contact

PersonMailingLongitude <- MailingLatitude (from Contact)
PersonMailingLongitude <- MailingLongitude (from Contact)
text_field__c <- Title (from Contact)

I did check the Contact record, and those 3 fields are all populated.

Now the flow runs and when I look at the record, only the text_field__c is populated.

And when I 'debug' the flow, it shows me step by step and the lat/long are null there in the debug... but If i go to the Contact record, they are NOT null and they have a value.

so Why isnt it actually saving?

[image]

[image]